# minimal configuration for using WebApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, configuration

I have this test class's code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class CandidateControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wac;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void before() {
         mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(wac).build();

    }
...
}
```

After execution code above I see  this trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.test.web.server.setup.InitializedContextMockMvcBuilder.<init>(InitializedContextMockMvcBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.test.web.server.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(MockMvcBuilders.java:73)
    at controllers.CandidateControllerTest.before(CandidateControllerTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I think problem with `classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml`.

I don't know what I need write at this file for correct working.

Can you wite explain me minimal conditions for correct execution this code ?

Comment: can you confirm the location of BeanConfig.xml ist correct and post it?

Comment: what autowiring strategy do you use inside the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not running your test class with Spring, just normal Junit. You need to use Spring's test runner otherwise the `@Autowired` is meaningless and the field remains `null`.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CandidateControllerTest {
```